# Why does `tslint` report `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` even I checked it before use?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I am using `typescript` in React project. I have below code in `typescript`:

```
if(this.state.deletedItem !== null) {
                this.props.deleteItem({refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx});
              }
```

tslint gives me an error `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` on the object `this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx`. It says `this.state.deletedItem` could be null. But I already checked it in the `if` condition and why it still reports such error?

Below is the type definition:

```
interface State {
  deletedItem: ItemDiscountTranItem | null;
}

export class MainView extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state = {
    deletedItem: null,
  };
  ...
```

I have tried to update the code as below but still get the error:

```
         if(this.state.deletedItem) {
            this.props.voidItemDiscount({refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem ? this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx : 0});
          }
```

I tried below syntax and still get the same error:

```
this.props.voidItemDiscount({refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem && this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
interface State {
  deletedItem: ItemDiscountTranItem | null;
}
```

This line indicate that: 
 + `deletedItem` **have to** be in the `State`
 + The `deletedItem` could be null

Since it could be `null` and have to be there at the same time
When you call `{refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx}`
the `deletedItem` could be `null` then javascript will throw error, something like this `can not read property itemIdx of null`, sort of.
`typescript` help you indicate that problem first with the `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.` to preventing further error.

So you should declare your interface like this:

```
interface State {
  deletedItem?: ItemDiscountTranItem;
}
```

`{refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem && this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx}`

This indicate that:
 + You **could or could have** the `deletedItem` in your interface
 + And the `deletedItem` is type of `ItemDiscountTranItem`
And you can get the value through checking whether the `this.state.deletedItem` is exist or not then get the `itemIdx` out of it.

=====================
Here is just my thought, it's good if you consider using it.
That is, I usually let the `variables` or something that related to the `global context` or `application state` in your case is `State` 
Have a default value and **reduce** as much `null` and `undefined` as possible. 
You can declare your state like this 
    `deletedItems: ItemDiscountTranItem[]`,

There is no harm in this declaration, and in fact, it help your code more readable and extendable, 
**Eg**: you can check whether there is anything to delete by simply `if(state.deletedItems.length)` 
and you can even further loop throw the list of `deletedItems.forEach`
 
what next? you don't even have to scratch your head about when this should be `null` is it `undefined`? or when should I check that?, you can leave all of that behind.

Because it now is simple, you want to `delete` something? you check if there is something to delete, you want to `delete more`? you loop. `simple enough`.

Comment: I have tried this approach but it gives me the same error.

Comment: you could try `{refItemIdx: this.state.deletedItem && this.state.deletedItem.itemIdx}`

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot about the interface that you declared, I have edit the answer, hope that could help.

Comment: The state `deletedItem` can be null in my application. How can I handle that?

Comment: I figured out the problem and posted an answer. Please let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

The problem about my code is that I declared my component class as `class MainView extends React.Component<Props, State>`. The `State` here only indicate that the component state extends from this class. So the component state defined below has a narrow type of `State` which is `null`.

```
state = {
   deletedItem: null,
};
```

below change fixed my problem:

```
state: State = {
   deletedItem: null,
};
```

Comment: yep, if it works then it good to go, but I have edited my answer with my thought under it, hope it helpful for you.